# DynamoDB Query with equality on PK and Begins with on SK in Go using Expressions package

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to write a Query operation on a DynamoDB table with Go. I am trying to duplicate the following CLI command:

```
aws dynamodb query \
  --table-name myTable \
  --index-name name-index \
  --key-condition-expression "_pk = :dpid and begins_with(st, :st)" \
  --expression-attribute-values  '{":dpid":{"S":"dp#1"}, ":st":{"S":"jam"}}'
```

Note the `_` in front of the `_pk`.

I am trying to use the [Expressions package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression), but I find the docs super confusing. So far I have:

```
func (p *PatientStore) SearchPatients(ctx context.Context, searchTerm string) ([]PatientSearchResponseItem, error) {
    dentalPracticeId := "dp#1"
    lowerCaseSearchTerm := strings.ToLower(searchTerm)
    var err error
    var response *dynamodb.QueryOutput
    var patients []PatientSearchResponseItem
    keyEx := expression.Key("_pk").Equal(expression.Value(dentalPracticeId))
    gsiCondition := expression.BeginsWith(expression.Name("st"), lowerCaseSearchTerm) // gsiCondition declared but not used error
    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithKeyCondition(keyEx).Build()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't build epxression for query. Here's why: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        response, err = p.client.Query(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.QueryInput{
            TableName:                 aws.String(p.tableName),
            IndexName:                 jsii.String("name-index"),
            ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
            ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
            KeyConditionExpression:    expr.KeyCondition(),
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Couldn't query for patients matching %v. Here's why: %v\n", lowerCaseSearchTerm, err)
        } else {
            err = attributevalue.UnmarshalListOfMaps(response.Items, &patients)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Couldn't unmarshal query response. Here's why: %v\n", err)
            }
        }
    }

    return patients, err
}
```

Right now, I'm getting an error that states that the `gsiCondition is declared but not used`, which makes sense, but I don't know how to use that condition. The docs don't show how to have multiple conditions.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at our examples on GitHub?

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/example_code/dynamodb/DynamoDBScanItems.go

This should give you the information you require.

As for the exception, you cannot declare expressionAttributeValues/Names and not use them, it they are no needed for the request you can simply omit them.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"
)

func main() {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), func(o *config.LoadOptions) error {
        o.Region = "eu-west-1"
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    svc := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    out, err := svc.Query(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName:              aws.String("test"),
        KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#pk = :pk and #sk > :sk"),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            ":pk":  &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "lhnng"},
            ":sk": &types.AttributeValueMemberN{Value: "500"},
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]string{
            "#pk": "_pk",
            "#sk": "sk",
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(out.Items)
}
```

Comment: Hi Lee, I had a look but didn't see what I was after? In my case, it is a key condition that I want (at least that's my understanding), yet I don't see that in the link you've posted. Also, this is doing a `Scan` instead of a `Query` but I don't think that matters much in terms of the expression syntax.

Comment: I have added a sample of a Query from my local machine. Let me know if it suits your needs?

Comment: I *really* want to achieve this with the [Expression package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression). Can it be done with that?

Comment: Also, the above wouldn't work cause in my case I have `_`, and that is reserved in Dynamo.

Comment: It would work:

 ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]string{
            "#pk": "_pk",
        },

Comment: Updated my answer to include _pk

Comment: Thanks Lee, that worked, I want to see if this can be done with the Expressions package too.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here just for the benefit of others. I was able to solve it with expressions

```
var condition = expression.Name("pk").Equal(expression.Value("pkValue")).And(expression.Name("sk").BeginsWith("skValue"))
condExp, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithCondition(condition).Build()
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("error building expression: %w", err)
}

response, err := svc.Query(c, &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:                 &tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression:    condExp.Condition(),
    ExpressionAttributeNames:  condExp.Names(),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: condExp.Values(),
})
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed reading data: %w", err)
}
```